# Restricting the user to scroll the mouse wheel untill the css animation completes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a several functions , each one called upon the mouse wheel up and down , these functions need to be called in a particular order , but the problem is that when the user scroll faster these function are called without the completion of CSS animation contained in the previous function , how can i assure that the all previous Css animation completes before the users scrolls further.

Comment: please post some sample code!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('html, body').css({
    'overflow': 'hidden',
    'height': '100%'
});

$(".element").on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function() {
    // restore
    $('html, body').css({
        'overflow': 'auto',
        'height': 'auto'
    });
});
```

At first the scrolling will be disabled via CSS and then, after the transition of the element `.element` is completed, this CSS will be reset and scrolling is possible again.

Comment: Thanks for replying , but the solution above is not working for me.

Comment: Then please post a sample code so that we can verify that. The best way would be a live preview at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer , by 'transitionend'  i can track the end of css animation and then disable the mouse scroll.